# How use BD created in the first execution

Tags: cordova, sqlite

First, sorry for my poor English.

I followed the official documentation on the storage API. I created a database each time an application starts.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

I need to create the database in the first execution of the application, but I need to use in future executions and data base created in the first execution without creating it again, how is this possible?

The OpenDatabase method (...) returns a new BD.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Um, no, openDatabase won't create a new database after it is run once. If you are seeing different, please post more details.